# Unity raw RGB24 coding is mirrored

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, image-processing

So I have this C# on unity code:

```
public void saveScreenshot (int loc)
{
    TextureFormat fmt = TextureFormat.RGB24;
    m_screenshot = new Texture2D (Screen.width, Screen.height, fmt, false);
    m_screenshot.ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    m_screenshot.Apply ();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/output.rgb24", m_screenshot.GetRawTextureData ());
}
```

Which is used to save an image in `RGB24` format. I later use this output as input to `VideoBox` so I can encode a video from a constant stream of screenshots (in the non-debugging application the buffer is saved to the memory instead of a file)

The problem is unity saves the image correctly, only the image is mirrored as the attached image shows.

Reversing the array in CPU beats the point of using GPU acceleration, do I really have no idea how to undo this...

Any ideas?[image: Reversed image]

Comment: What happens when you save it as png `m_screenshot.EncodeToPNG();` ? Is the problem still there?

Comment: Nope, PNG works just fine

Comment: I noticed that you are sing it as as ".rgb24" with `GetRawTextureData`. The function `GetRawTextureData` returns byte array in Unity raw format and to load it you use `LoadRawTextureData`. Don't expect to save it with `GetRawTextureData` and open it like a normal image with an outside program like paint...

Comment: Definitely not with paint (; but I do use YUView to display the raw buffer after specifying the width, height and encoding (since there's no header). Unity clearly states this is an RGB24 encoding - which is true, but the image is mirrored...

Comment: RGB24 isn't a _file_ format but a _data_ format, and the flipped lines are a typical bitmap line save order. Why do you care if it's flipped though? You say "I later use this output as input", but if that's where this image comes from, you also need to post that loading code. But, if it _does_ display okay at that point... what is your problem? Just that the lines are reversed in the buffer file? Why would you care?

Comment: Hi @Nyerguds. For simplicity, I omitted the part where I use this input. I'm using the raw RGB24 data with VideoBox to encode it into h264 and create an MP4. The reason I care it is flipped is the final video looks reversed... There is no option in VideoBox to flip the image, so I must resort to unity....

Comment: Well, it's rather normal that if you take raw input from one thing and use it in another thing, some conversion may be needed. I don't see how GPU acceleration is even relevant in that. It's just going over all lines and reversing them; it's not that hard to do.

Comment: @Nyerguds oh but it is... Reversing the image by cpu costs a drop of 28 fps in iOS applications on iPad 3. Even just reading the pixels drops the fps to 17. These are very expansive operations! Using a gpu you get parallel calculation of all pixels

Comment: The place to fix this is probably the receiving code, since that's the place that actually needs to process the buffer, but since you never gave it, I have no idea what kind of fix to suggest for it.

Comment: @Nyerguds I'm afraid the receiving end is VideoToolbox, it accepts a raw rgb buffer with frame dimensions and encodes it to h264 frames. As this code is Apple proprietary, and there is no rotation method anywhere within it, this is not the place to rotate...

Comment: Well, you could try exporting to png bytes, loading those as Bitmap object, 
 getting the bytes out of that with LockBits and using those, but that'll probably be a lot slower than the manual flipping. Still, could try it as experiment. You never know.

Comment: First thing I tried was working with the PNG... Slow as hell (;